# does vi have a bug which changes spaces in unedited lines, or is there an option to turn this "feature" off?

Tags: vim, osx, bugs

[image]

I changed a file by just adding a few lines, then ran a git diff and found changes strewn throughout the file resembling as shown in the image above:  an extra space at the end of a line in the middle of a comment.

These affect git merge and other developers are complaining I should stop using vim.

Is this a bug in vim?  Or is a default feature I can turn off?

Comment: `vim` doesn't do this by default. If it does, it's either because you've configured to do so, or because a plugin you have installed is doing it.

Comment: It looks like you have either a plugin of an `autocmd` that removes trailing spaces on write.  Vim doesn't do that by itself.